# RAML - Null Value accepting in String Type in Query Param

Tags: api, mulesoft, raml

I have created a Query Params for an API and one of the Params is mentioned as below,

```
Testing:
  description:
  required: true
  type: string
  example: “ABCDEFG”
```

During the mock testing, I could see null value was getting accepted for this Query Param. Could you please confirm whether null is a acceptable value when the Type is String ?? If it is a acceptable will there any way that it accepts only characters whereas null and empty quotes are not accepted ?? Thanks.

Note:- I tried with all these values Null, null and nil . All values are accepted and it doesnt throw error.

Adding Example:-

> API URL:-
> http://localhost:8081/api/patient?patientLongitude=10&patientLatitude=20&Testing=Abcd
> Response:- Success(Correct)
>
> API URL:-
> http://localhost:8081/api/patient?patientLongitude=10&patientLatitude=20&Testing=""
> Response:- Success(Expecting Failure response since Testing QueryParam
> is an empty Quotes)
>
> API URL:-
> http://localhost:8081/api/patient?patientLongitude=10&patientLatitude=20&Testing=null
> Response:- Success(Expecting Failure response since Testing QueryParam
> is an null)

> API URL:-
> http://localhost:8081/api/patient?patientLongitude=10&patientLatitude=20&Testing=
> Response:- Success(Expecting Failure response since Testing QueryParam
> doesn't have any value) - I can fix this by adding Min Length as 1 in RAML

Comment: Please show an HTTP request example, preferably with Curl in text format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to define the query param as nullable:

```
type: string | nil
```

Comment: My Question is It should not accept Null and Empty values

Comment: Please add some examples of actual requests with null and empty values.

Comment: Thanks for the Response. I have added few example. I hope its helpful. I am trying to understand the behavior of String Type in Query Params and also trying to check if there is any way we can handle the example of 3 and 4 in RAML Itself.